# PHP - Display image based on email

Tags: php, image, session, mysqli, display

I am looking for some help.
Need to create a branding page, that upon logging in would display an image based on user's email that's stored in the database.
Creating a cookie and session id works just fine. Just can't find a way to select image based on user's email.
Pasting just part of the code that actually handles user id, as anything else in my index.php file is pure html.

So far:

```
<?php
include 'function.php';
include 'sqlconnect.php';

//User Check
$adminid = "1";

$company1= "@gmail.com";
$company2= "@yahoo.com";

$gmail= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE Email='$company1'");
$yahoo= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE Email='$company2'");

if(loggedin()){
    $checkid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    if ($adminid == $checkid){ //if user id is 1 then display img of administrator
        echo '<img src="images/admin.png" title="Administrator" width:"75px" height="75px">';
        echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";
    } elseif(filter_var($company1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('/@.+\.gmail/', $company1)) {
        echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";
        echo '<img src="images/google.png">';
    } elseif (filter_var($company2, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('/@.+\.yahoo/',$company2)) {
        echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";
        echo '<img src="images/yahoo.png>';
    }
}

?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So You need The User page based on domain like Yahoo or Gmail right? so if its yahoo it should be yahoo logo like that

Comment: That's the plan. If @ gmail.com then show google logo, else if @ yahoo.com then show yahoo logo. But that has to be based on user email that's stored in sql database.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working yet?

Comment: To be a bit more specific, my code does not seem to understand I want @ google email users to display an image, and same for yahoo email bit.

Comment: It may be that your select statements are querying for values with `Email='@yahoo.com'` and `Email='@gmail.com'` .  I am pretty sure that you're looking to find values with `Email like '%@yahoo.com%'` and  `Email like '%@gmail.com%'`

Comment: Should this part: elseif(filter_var($company1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('/@.+\.gmail/', $company1)) remain in the code? Or your suggestion is enough, and I should get rid of this whole pregmatch thing?

Comment: I would try it first with the updated query, and if it works at that point, then see if it works without the checks

Comment: I've tried both to be honest. However it seems to pick up the first part (company 1) even when logging in with company 2 email.

Comment: Now I understand your problem better.  At no point in your code are you incorporating the `user_id` in your query, and the filter_var/preg_match is only checking the `company` variables which are also unrelated to your query.  If I understand correctly, you are trying to pull the customer information *based on user_id*, and then check the `Email` field to see if it ends with '@yahoo.com` or `@gmail.com`.   I should be able to give an answer if you can verify?

Comment: Yes that's pretty much correct. It's just the code driving me crazy, been trying to solve it for the past 2 weeks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get your user based on the session's `user_id` then display the image as expected.  Here are a few notes:

1. I wasn't sure what your id field was, so if it is different, replace `UserId` with the name of your column in the `$results =` line.
2. I did not run the query in the case that it is an admin, so if you need data for something else in that case, you'll have to move the `$result = ..` line to above the `if ($userid == 1){` line.
3. I didn't check the regex for your `preg_match` conditions, so if the results are coming in, but the image isn't being displayed, you can see what the `Email` field is by adding `echo <p>'.$result['Email'].'</p>` right after the `if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {` line.

   ```
   <?php
   include 'function.php';
   include 'sqlconnect.php';

   if(loggedin()){
       $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];    
       if ($userid == 1){ //if user id is 1 then display img of administrator
           echo '<img src="images/admin.png" title="Administrator" width:"75px" height="75px">';
           echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";
       } else {
           $results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE UserId='$userid'");
           if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
               foreach(mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) as $result) {
                   echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";
                   if (strpos($result,'yahoo')) {
                       echo '<img src="images/yahoo.png>';
                   } elseif (strpos($result,'gmail')) {
                       echo '<img src="images/google.png">';
                   } else {
                       // you could echo a default image here
                   }
               } 
           }
       }
   }

   ?>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this actually breaks login function IF it's not an admin trying to login. Ie Logout button only appears for admin user (id = 1), but otherwise it doesn't seem to start a session or anything. Even default image doesn't pop up.

Comment: @PHPhunter I forgot to add the actual fetching of the results for the output.  If this still doesn't work, it is either because your query isn't returning anything or the UserId field is not unique and the query is returning more than one user.  Alternatively, it could be that the `$connection` is not being set correctly, as I do not have that code to check.

Comment: In any case, I would highly recommend researching the basics of php/mysqli connections.  [this is a good place to start](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#example-1934)

Comment: Thank you mtr.web. $connection is fine, as it's being used all the time across all other files, such as register, login and create event (assignment with a charity background). It's just this thing that I cannot figure out how it's supposed to actually look like. I tried your edit, but the result is still the same (not even logged in as standard user, but admin displays things just fine). // Just noticed that you changed $checkid into $userid. Changing this seems to login fine, but  gives "Illegal string offset Email" line 60 (which starts to be elseif pregmatch line)

Comment: I guess the next step is checking the user_id/UserId values, the test queries, and drilling through your $results variable to see what it is returning.

Comment: I just edited my above comment. Part of the issue was indeed $userid (originally I got it $checkid) We are almost there, but not yet. I did echo $result and it seems to pick up a whole email (johnsmith@gmail.com) but still goes to the "default" bit, while saying that "illegal string offset Email".

Comment: @PHPhunter I changed the answer just to eliminate preg_replace() as a problem.  Can you provide the output of your `echo $result`?

Comment: So that somewhat did the trick. 'Email' is still said to be illegal string offset. But: 1 Logging in as yahoo shows GMAIL image and message (and vice versa). 2. Admin login is still 
 just fine.

Comment: @PHPhunter I cannot be sure without the full output of your `echo $result` but the last edit *may* account for the error that you are getting

Comment: $result remains to be a full email. I made it echo for yahoo user, while $result displays johnsmith@gmail.com . And echo for gmail user displays johnny@yahoo.com.

Comment: @PHPhunter The actual output is what I am looking for.  It is going to be one of three things: `[0] => 'johnny@gmail.com'`, `['somekeythatineedtoknow'] => 'johnny@gmail.com'` or just `johnny@gmail.com`.  If the last is the case, the most recent edit should have fixed it

Comment: Most recent edit stops any sort of matching, and automatically goes straight to default message (if neither gmail nor yahoo exists). Keeps logged in however. $result remains to be the email.

Comment: @PHPhunter At this point, I cannot help unless you give me the **full output as it appears** for `echo $result` and the exact code that you are using to echo it.

Comment: With the ['Email'] it tries to match emails but other way around...       Warning
: Illegal string offset 'Email' in
/srv/disk2/2644355/www/host/index.php
on line
54


Warning
: Illegal string offset 'Email' in
/srv/disk2/2644355/www/host/index.php
on line
58

GMAIL USER spot@yahoo.com               And without ['Email'] It goes directly to default image and message, without errors or trying to match an email.

Comment: @PHPhunter please refer to my last comment

Comment: Nothing else shows up than what I just pasted.. Unless I am missing some sort of debugging/error handling code?

Comment: @PHPhunter before `echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";` add a line like this: `echo '<li>'.$result.'</li>';`  If it turns out that it is an array, change the line to `echo '<li>'.implode(',', $result).'</li>';` and let me know what the results are

Comment: sorry for late reply. For first `.$result` it displays a full email I log in as. For `implode $result` , it tells me `Warning
: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in`. I spoke with my teacher, and he believes the issue might be `foreach`. But didn't want to give more advise than this...

Comment: Ok thank you @mtr.web. The issue was strpos being other way around. Should have been `($result, 'yahoo')` and not `('yahoo', $result)`

Comment: @PHPhunter, I am glad this is finally working for you.  I will edit the answer to reflect your changes